# Plotting hemisphere using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

Can anyone help me with the plotting using tikz? I would like to plot the figure below in tikz but I do not know where to start. I have checked the examples given using "ball", yet I cannot find anything which deals with a hemisphere.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [dashed] (0,0) arc (180:0:4 and 2) ;
\draw (0,0) arc (180:360:4 and 2) ;
\draw [dashed] (0,0.5) arc (180:0:3.95 and 2) ;
\draw (0,0.5) arc (180:360:3.95 and 2) ;
\draw (0,0) arc (180:0:4 and 4);
\draw (5.5, 1.5) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image: Sky dome]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: @cfr, I do not know how to do this efficiently. Two particular things puzzle me, 1) how to make the angles representation (i.e., the two way arrows) exactly correspond to the two lines defining the angle; 2) when the lines passing through the small circle, how to make them "dashed". I appreciate your help.

Comment: For the angles, have you looked at the `angles` library included in `tikz`?

Comment: You might find some inspiration/starting points in a few similar TeXample.net examples: [1](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/spherical-and-cartesian-grids/) [2](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/map-projections/) [3](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/the-3dplot-package/)

Comment: @PaulGessler, thank you for the links. I have checked those example before I posted the question. I like the first two examples, however, they use the object ball. Is there anything similar for a hemisphere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are my two cents. It's a simple *freehand drawn* and no mathematical correct drawing. It is more a POC with pseudo 3d-code and many code that could be written much more sophisticated. Just take this as some additional ideas to complete your work.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=6mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 % base circle
 \draw (-4,0) arc (180:360:4 and 1);
 \draw [dashed] (-4,0) arc (180:0:4 and 1);
 % circle above base circle
 \draw (-3.95,.5) arc (180:360:3.95 and 1);
 \draw [dashed] (-3.95,.5) arc (180:0:3.95 and 1);
 % hemisphere
 \draw (-4,0) arc (180:0:4 and 4);
 % circle on hemisphere and point in it
 \draw (2,2) circle (1);
 \draw (2,2) node [circle, fill=black, inner sep=.05cm, label={[label distance=-.25cm]95:$F_1xL$}] (dot) {};
 % rectangles at zero
 \draw (0,0,0) -- ++(0,-.5,-.5) -- ++(0,.5,0) -- ++(0,.5,.5) -- cycle;
 \draw (0,0) -- ++(-.5,0) -- ++(0,.5) -- ++(.5,0) -- cycle;
 % x and spanning xi
 \draw [thick, dashed] (0,0) -- ++(-5,0);
 \draw [thick] (0,0) -- ++(172.5:5cm);
 % y
 \draw [thick, dashed] (0,0) -- ++(0,5);
 % z
 \draw [thick, dashed] (0,0,0) -- ++(0,-2.5,-2.5);
 % lines spanning angle alpha
 \draw [thick] (0,0) -- ++(45:5cm);
 \draw [thick] (0,0) -- ++(30:5cm);
 % angle labels
 \draw [red, thick, <->] (0,0) ++(172.5:4.5cm) arc (172.5:180:4.5cm) node [midway, left] () {$\xi$};
 \draw [red, thick, <->] (0,0) ++(30:4.5cm) arc (30:45:4.5cm) node [midway, above right] () {$\alpha$};  
 \draw [red, thick, <->] (0,0) ++(90:1.5cm) arc (90:45:1.5cm) node [midway, above] () {$\theta h$};
 % other labels
 \draw (0,-.75) node () {$F_2xL$};
 \draw (-1,2) node () {L};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Hemisphere]